# Replace placeholder of HTML file in JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using **jsoup** library to parse HTML file in Java. 
I want to replace placeholders of that HTML file. 
Presently I am putting the placeholders in `<span id = "id_1"> xx </span>` and replacing them.

I have tried to do many other things, but didn't achieve success.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("abc.html"), UTF_8);
    doc.getElementById("id_1").text("MUKUL");
```

Placeholders in my html file are like `<%= name %>`. I want to replace all placeholders with suitable value. For now I had made change in my html file to put placeholders in `<span id = "id_1"> xx </span>` tag. I don't want to change my html template.

Can anyone please suggest some clean and better way to achieve this thing.

**Why I am not changing it to String**: I don't want to change the html file in String because html file contains some Japanese characters and whenever I transform it to string, some of the Japanese characters distort and produces some junk data.

Comment: is your file .jsp ?

Comment: no. it's html file